Using perfect tenses or not

I was working for 2 hours before you

I already painted the walls when you arrived


Is 1 a valid sentence or because I used "for 2 hours" I should have used past perfect continuous?
Would you accept 2 as correct or it also needs perfect?

"Should I have used...?" "Does it also need...?"

As a British English speaker I would say I had already painted the walls, but American usage may differ.

As an American English speaker I too would say I had already painted the walls.

Americans tend not to use perfect tenses as much as Brits, but I agree that we would use it here.

What about 1 guys
